# the eigenvalue and eigenfunction of Laplace operator on the rectangle domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

Let $Q = \{ (x, y): 0 < x < a , 0 < y <b \}$. Solve the problem:
$$
- \Delta u (x, y) = \lambda u(x, y), ~ u \Bigr|_{ \delta Q} = 0.
$$

P.S. I know the theorem about eigenvalue of Dirichlet problem: any eigenvalue of the Laplace operator $\lambda$ is real, positive and each $\lambda$ has finite multiplicity. But I don't know how to find a solution of this task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community , I need to solve the specified boundary value problem. Sorry,  I don't understand what do I need to fix in the condition

Comment: Have you seen any similar problem before?

Comment: @ArcticChar , this task was given as an exercise to the theorem. which I indicated in the postscript.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the same theorem in an interval?

Comment: @ArcticChar , do you mean $ u''(x) = \lambda  u(x) , x \in (0, 1) $ for exampe. Yes, I know solution of this task. It is linear differential equation with constant coefficients of the second order.

Comment: Do you know separation of variables?

Comment: @ArcticChar I don't know this method for solution partial differential equation

Comment: Start by looking at $\varphi_{n,m}(x,y)=\sin(n\pi x/a)\sin(m\pi y/b)$ for positive integers $n,m$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts .
If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting to represent $u(x, y) = X(x) + Y(y)$, then we get: $ X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = -(Y''(y) - \lambda Y(y)  ) $. The last equation is equivalent to the system of two ordinary differential equations: $ X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = C ; -(Y''(y) - \lambda Y(y)  ) = -C$. Of course, I can solution it. I am concerned about a question. Can we lose solutions with such a replacement?

Comment: @silent : $\varphi_{n,m}$ is one solution of your problem for all positive integers $n,m$. The $\lambda$ changes with $n,m$, but they are solutions. Moreover $\{ \sin(n\pi x/a) \}$ is a complete orthogonal subset of $L^2[0,a]$ and $\{ \sin(n\pi y/b) \}$ is a complete orthogonal subset of $L^2[0,b]$. And $\{ \sin(n\pi x/a)\sin(m\pi y/a) \}$ is a complete orthogonal subset of $L^2([0,a]\times[0,b])$. What happens if you expand a solution for a general $\lambda$ in terms of these?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, I understand your idea. Can you check my solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

consider the Fourier series on the segment $(0, 2a)$: $ \{ \sin \left({ \frac{\pi n }{a}x} \right) \}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ and   the Fourier series on the segment $(0, 2b)$: $ \{ \sin \left({ \frac{\pi m }{b}y} \right) \}_{m=1}^{\infty}$. Any $f(x , y) \in C^2( \overline{Q}) , f \bigr|_{\delta Q} = 0 $  is provided as
$$
f(x, y) = \sum_{1 \leq n, m < + \infty } a(n, m)  \sin \left({ \frac{\pi n }{a}x} \right)  \sin \left({ \frac{\pi m }{b}y} \right) 
$$
find $- \Delta f(x, y)$ :
$$
-\Delta f(x, y) = \sum_{1 \leq n, m < + \infty } \lambda(n, m) a(n, m)  \sin \left({ \frac{\pi n }{a}x} \right)  \sin \left({ \frac{\pi m }{b}y} \right), ~ \lambda(n, m) = \pi^2 \left( \frac{n^2}{a^2} + \frac{m^2}{b^2} \right) 
$$
Finally, we get if $ -\Delta f(x, y) = \lambda f(x, y)$, then $\lambda(n, m) = \lambda$ , therefore only $\phi_{nm}(x , y)$ are eigenfunctions and $\lambda(n , m)$ are eigenvalues in this task.

Comment: So $-\Delta f = \lambda f$ for some $\lambda$ implies $\lambda = \lambda(n,m)$ for some $n,m$ and all other $\lambda(n',m')=0$. This follows by the uniqueness of the $L^2$ expansion. So $\lambda=\lambda(n,m)$ for some $n,m$ and the eigenfunction is $\sin(n\pi x/a)\sin(m\pi y/b)$. The existence and uniqueness of $\sin$ expansions on an interval is basically all you need.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, thank's for remarks!